# uploading multi images to the server with swift using Alamofire or anyway to achieve that from the first step to know how we use it with image picker

Tags: ios, swift, iphone, post, alamofire

I need to know how can I select multiple images and upload them to the server with another params using Alamofire or any other way from the begining

### what I really need to see is how can I use image picker with this way

1-> use imgaePicker in swift
2-> full function using your own way of uploading images and many thanks because I don't understand how can I get images from image picker

Answer (score 0, accepted):

finally I got an easy answer using a pod called OpalImagePicker and the way is so easy using Alamofire:

### code from the first to understand

```
import Alamofire
import ImagePicker
import Photos
import OpalImagePicker

class PostVC: UIViewController,UITextViewDelegate,UINavigationControllerDelegate,UIImagePickerControllerDelegate, ImagePickerDelegate,OpalImagePickerControllerDelegate {

var arryOfImages = [UIImage]()

// you have to put them don't worry about those funcs
func wrapperDidPress(_ imagePicker: ImagePickerController, images: [UIImage]) {
    print("picked")
}

func doneButtonDidPress(_ imagePicker: ImagePickerController, images: [UIImage]) {
    print("done")

func cancelButtonDidPress(_ imagePicker: ImagePickerController) {
    print("cancel")
}
```

// set in your button action to get images the image/video .. etc and num of    them

---

```
@IBAction func addPicture_clicked(_ sender: Any) {
        let imagePicker = OpalImagePickerController()
                imagePicker.imagePickerDelegate = self
                imagePicker.maximumSelectionsAllowed = 3
        imagePicker.allowedMediaTypes = Set([PHAssetMediaType.image]) //you can select only images set this
                present(imagePicker, animated: true, completion: nil)


    }

func imagePicker(_ picker: OpalImagePickerController, didFinishPickingImages images: [UIImage]){
    print(images)
     self.arryOfImages = images
    picker.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nill
    
}
```

---

### The Request You Want

//finally the request and thank you ^^

---

```
func addPostClicked(){

        guard let text = postTextView.text else {
                    return
                }
        let token = "UYJ9ohx_M6JvDbJu0"
        
        let profileId = 104
        let params : [String: Any] = [
                    "postText" :text,
                    "profileId":profileId
        ]
        
   
            Alamofire.upload(
                multipartFormData: { multipartFormData in
                    var count = 1
                for img in self.arryOfImages {
                    //here we send our images
                    let imageData = img.jpegData(compressionQuality: 0.5)
                        multipartFormData.append(imageData!, withName: "images[]", fileName: "image\(count).jpeg", mimeType: "image/jpeg")
                    count += 1
                }

                for (key, value) in params
                {
                    multipartFormData.append("\(value)".data(using: String.Encoding.utf8)!, withName: key)
                    
                }
            }, to:"https://api.yoogad.com/rest/api/v1/post/create", method:.post, headers: ["x-auth-token" : token],encodingCompletion: { encodingResult in
            switch encodingResult {
              case .success(let upload, _, _):
                    upload.responseJSON { response in
                    debugPrint(response)
                        self.dismiss(animated: true)
                    }
              case .failure(let encodingError):
                   print(encodingError)
              }
            })
           }
```